# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: silverlight, reflection

I'm tring to create a generic collection of dynamic type at runtime of Silverlight application. My code:

```
Type listType =
  Type.GetType("System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[["
                 + type.AssemblyQualifiedName
                 + "]], System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
               true);
```

`type` is a variable of `Type` type. That Type is creating at runtime. At that code line I've got error:

> Could not load file or assembly ', Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I resolve that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MakeGenericType` instead:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```